# Android Lollipop: Webview .svg file support

Tags: android, svg, android-webview, android-websettings, androidsvg

I am working on application which loads data from server in webview. This data contains icons which are coming from .svg file. Problem is icons are rendering properly lower versions of Android, but in android lollipop instead of icon it shows random text.SVG file is added through css inside a html code which we load in webview.

Does any one know android Web View supports .SVG in Android lollipop?

Or

Do I required to do Lollipop specific changes on server side?

Thank You

Comment: Nope we load a html template in webview not just svg file

Comment: Some actual code would be helpful.  Could you explain what you mean by "SVG file is added through css inside a html code which we load in webview."